# VBA Loop through files in a directory, save as csv in another directory, skip if file exists

Tags: excel, vba, do-while

I have a bit of code that loops through a bunch of files in a folder, runs a macro on each of them, and then saves them as a .csv file in a different folder. The process runs fine with if the destination csv folder is empty. What I want to do is skip the process if the .csv file already exists. The problem with the code below, is that the Filename = Dir() returns a null value and the loop ends if the .csv file exists. So how do I continue looping through the other files in the first folder?

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
Dim Filename, Pathname, strFileExists As String
Dim wb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Files\"
Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")
Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
    length = Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
    Name = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, length - 5)
    CSVName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\CSV Files\" & Name & ".csv"
    strFileExists = Dir(CSVName)

    If strFileExists = "" Then
        Transform wb 'Run Transform function
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=CSVName, FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Filename = Dir()
    Else
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Filename = Dir()
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: have a look to the filesystem object that can be used in VBA. Much more powerfull than the standard functions like dir. As far as I remember it was a differnce in dir function, if the pathname ends with backslash or not. But anyway - filesystem object will be your friend

Comment: You are calling `strFileExists = Dir(CSVName)` (with an argument) in the middle of the loop. That resets the `Dir` function so that the next `Dir()` (without an argument) no longer does what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: The filesystem object worked wonders! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think braX is right: the problem is you are using Dir twice. This seems to be working for me:

```
Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim Filename, Pathname, strFileExists As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim IntFileNumber As Integer
    Dim IntCounter01 As Integer
    Dim Length As Byte
    Dim Name As String
    Dim CSVName As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Files\"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")

    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)
        Length = Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
        Name = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Length - 5)
        CSVName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\CSV Files\" & Name & ".csv"
        strFileExists = Dir(CSVName)


        If strFileExists = "" Then
            Transform wb 'Run Transform function
            wb.SaveAs Filename:=CSVName, FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")
            IntFileNumber = IntFileNumber + 1
            For IntCounter01 = 1 To IntFileNumber
                Filename = Dir()
            Next
        Else
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsx")
            IntFileNumber = IntFileNumber + 1
            For IntCounter01 = 1 To IntFileNumber
                Filename = Dir()
            Next
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Basically i reset the Filename and re-play Dir as many time as needed to reach the wanted file.

I've added some declarations too. You might also want to turn true the ScreenUpdating at the end of the subroutine, but that's up to you.